# why i can't unset session in php?

Tags: php, javascript, session

I'm writing some code to allow user to book a table in a restaurant. But my client asked me to allow user choose from the restaurant menu some items and then come back and reserve the table. If user don't want to choose menu then they may just ignore the step.

To do so I just printed a message "Do you want to choose menu?" and then a hyperlink to the menu page. I used iavascript onClick event to listen whether user clicked or not and if clicked I called a function setsession to set my session to track my user's activity in my website. I declared my function on top of the page.like-

```
    <script>
    function setsession(){
    <?php $_session['reservation']= TRUE;
    }
    </script>
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>Do you want to choose menu? Then <a href="somepage.php" onClick="setsession()">Click here.</a></p>
<p>rest of my code</p>
<p>confirm to reserve.</p>
<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="return Validate();submitform();">Confirm</a>
</form>

<?php if(isset($addnew) && !$error) ?>
<div class="success">
<p>sucess</p>
<?php $_SESSION['reservationprocess'] = FALSE;?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

everything worked fine. When I clicked on the hyperlink my session variable successfully. And when i clicked on confirm button (the hyperlink above) it successfully stores the data in database and pull the message success and unset the session.

but problem is I don't how and why my session set again. How much I tried to unset my session but I failed. my rest of the code working well and there are  no problem, as far I know. I've tested it. Is there any solution from the experts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you call `session_start()` at the top of the page?

Comment: yes. my site has a login system.

Comment: Couple things.. the PHP gets evaluated on the server before the javascript is rendered. I'm not sure you can update a php variable based on a javascript condition. Secondly, your first <?php tag does not have a closing tag. Again, not that I think it matters.

Comment: @Matt - some people write PHP without a final closing tag on purpose.  In some cases it can prevent bugs related to unintentional output.  In some cases it's considered a best practice.

Comment: @surrealDreams, I'm aware of the bugs caused by the closing tags in PHP, specifically in CMS systems. What are the advantages in this situation?

Comment: @Matt - the advantages... like avoiding bugs?  That's the one advantage I know.

Comment: @SurrealDreams, what bugs would adding an ending tag produce in this situation?

Comment: @MattMoore In this situation, none.  In certain situations, trailing spaces after a close php tag can cause errors because the script outputs the spaces before headers are sent, causing errors.

Comment: @SurrealDreams, thanks for the clarification. I didn't think adding a closing tag would cause any problems here.

Comment: @MattMoore you're absolutely correct.  Leaving it off won't hurt either.  I'm with you, actually - I much prefer to close them on purpose so I know I finished what I was doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry to disturb you again. But this time not to ask some novice question, but to answer my own question.

First of all I'm going to write my question in brief. I wanted to catch a event and wanted to use the event to store some value in my session to recognize that event in rest of my site unless the session is destroyed by somehow.
Al the variables used in .php file stores value in them and execute all operations when they are on the server. Browser displays the result. How can we expect while a user do something [in my case clicked] and it simply store a value in a php variable while there are no php variables inside the browser. So what can we do is simply store the result in a javascript variable or go back to server and set the value to the variable.
To call the server using ajax is a method of experts and honestly speaking I don't know much of it. So I needed to look for something what i already know. Of course based on php. Finally I got the COOKIE.
To catch the event its obvious to use javascript. I used a event listener using jQuery and inside it I store a value in my browser's cookie. and then used both javascript and php to check the cookie in my website.
This has a fallback. If user disables the cookie then you won't have the option to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite un-natural, but to destroy the session you need to make sure that you've called `session_start()` before hand.

To destroy the session you can't do it within that JavaScript function. You're going to need to make a HTTP requests to the server, this requests will then need to trigger a 'PHP' function deleting your session.

From reading your comment on the post below i'm assuming that you only want to delete a single variable of the session. Maybe try this:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['reservationprocess']);
```

Comment: If PHP hasn't got the session started, how would it know what session to destroy?  That's why you must start it first.

Comment: From javascript just need to delete the PHPSID cookie.

Answer (score 0):

session have to be initialized (if there is no initialization before) session_start() will do, and another tip is to use session_destroy() istead unset.

Comment: I don't want to destroy all my session because I need my login system to work. I just want to unset this $_SESSION['reservationprocess'] variable. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to every one. I've found out where was my problem. I tried to set session when its not in the server, its already in my browser. That's why how much i tried i couldn't set its value. Only way I can do it, by an ajax. I'm working on it. When i get my answer i'll share with you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you should do here is move this call:

```
<?php $_session['reservation']= TRUE;?>
```

.. to your menu page. So when the menu page loads this session is set. Then when you're done you can unset the variable with session_destroy().

Comment: Thanks. But I need to set this session only when a user clicked on my link.

Comment: So your saying the Menu page is accessible from other parts of the site? You can add a hidden field to the $_POST array that specify that this link was click and then set up the session variable. You can do it anyway you want. Just saying I wouldn't do it the way you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

don't know why have you session variable in script without any reason 2ndly i think when ever you load you page your variable is assigned and that may be the reason that it sets again. put some kind of check when you intializing or assigning your variable.